# How to load local resource in Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

In my Chrome App,I want to load local resources such as audio from user's disk.
If I add the absolute path in my code, the Chrome says "not allowed to load local resource"...
So,how to achive it? Thx
Please this is app not extension.

Comment: You should provide the code which is generating the error.

Comment: You're going to need to ask the user to choose the location using the chrome.fileSystem API (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem). Chrome Apps have a sandboxed security model and can't go rooting around in your user's hard drive.

Comment: when I use the <audio> tag and the value of 'src' is absolute path such as "file:///home/user/music/demo.mp3",the chrome shows "not allowed to load local resource".how to achive it by this way?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome Apps are not allowed to access the user's file system directly. `file://` URLs are forbidden, as are all the other ways you might try for accessing a file like `/home/user/music/demo.mp3`. This is by design (so users can install a random Chrome App and trust that it isn't going to read or write their files).

However, Chrome Apps have several APIs available for accessing sandboxed file systems. Since your example is an MP3 file in `/home/user/music`, you probably should use [chrome.mediaGalleries](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/mediaGalleries), which will prompt the user for access to common media directories (like `/home/user/music`) at install time. Then you will be able to access certain file types in certain directories, and prompt the user for music and images in other directories.

As sowbug suggested, you could also use [chrome.fileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem), where you can prompt the user to open a file or directory of their choosing. This will give you access to all files in those directories, but you should only use this if you want non-media file types.